# How can I expand data between two dates?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to expand date range to individual dates and sort the data.

Basically, I want a set of data such as this [Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v76BW.png):

```
May 16, 2019    May 19, 2019    123
May 18, 2019    May 20, 2019    abc
May 26, 2019    May 29, 2019    xyz
```

and want the output to be:[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI5OQ.png)

```
May 16, 2019    123
May 17, 2019    123
May 18, 2019    123
May 18, 2019    abc 
May 19, 2019    abc 
May 26, 2019    xyz
May 27, 2019    xyz
```

Can this be done using a formula?

EDIT: How can I get the desired output for just one value? Say 123?

Comment: You want the formula to generate the dates in the first column of the output or are those supplied by the user?  Reason for asking, is how is it determined that a date of May 27th should be there?  Further more May 18th falls into two data ranges 123 and abc and both options are printed in the list. May 19th is also in both ranges but only abc is displayed.  how do you determine which range result to display when a date falls into more than one range?  What is to be displayed for dates that are not within a range?  What do you want for May 24th?

Comment: The date range for 123 is basically [May 16, 2019 , May 19, 2019)  meaning that May 16th is included but not May 19th (sort of like check-in check-out dates in a hotel). Maybe the solution will be easier to be figured out if we can start with just getting the output for 123?

Comment: people will need to know the answers to the other questions asked as well

Comment: I'm sure they would. I just think that it might be easier to handle the problem if we break it down first.

Comment: It'd be easier to develop a VBA macro to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 {TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A1):INDIRECT("B"&B1))), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(C1&"♦", DAYS(B1, A1)+1), "♦")) };
 {TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(C2&"♦", DAYS(B2, A2)+1), "♦")) };
 {TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A3):INDIRECT("B"&B3))), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(C3&"♦", DAYS(B3, A3)+1), "♦")) }})
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of expanding just one row of the data:

```
=ArrayFormula({TO_DATE(row(indirect("a"&A1&":A"&B1-1))),if(row(indirect("a"&A1&":A"&B1-1)),C1)})
```

[image]

You can develop this further to create a dynamic formula for several rows.

First create a helper column in column D which just contains the number of nights' stay:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A="","",B:B-A:A))
```

Then this will give the list of dates:

```
=ArrayFormula(to_date(vlookup(row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))),{sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D)-D:D+1,A:A},2)+
row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D)))-
vlookup(row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))),sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D)-D:D+1,1)))
```

And this will give the column C data:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))),{sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D)-D:D+1,C:C},2))
```

[image]

**Explanation.**

Columns E to J contain the steps in arriving at the final formula.

[image]

*Column E:*

```
=ArrayFormula(sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D))
```

This gives the running total of the nights' stay based on column D.

*Column F:*

```
=ArrayFormula(sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D)-D:D+1)
```

This gives the running total just up to the start date - needed to make the vlookup work later on.

*Column G:*

```
=ArrayFormula(row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))))
```

Numbers 1 to N, where N is the total nights' stay obtained from column D.

*Column H:*

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))),{sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D)-D:D+1,A:A},2))
```

The start dates of each date range.

*Column I:*

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))),sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D)-D:D+1,1))
```

Numbers corresponding to the start of each date range.

*Column J:*

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))),{sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D)-D:D+1,A:A},2)+
row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))))
```

Start date of each date range plus numbers 1 to N

*Column K:*

```
=ArrayFormula(to_date(vlookup(row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))),{sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D)-D:D+1,A:A},2)+
row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D)))-
vlookup(row(indirect("a1:A"&sum(D:D))),sumif(row(D:D),"<="&row(D:D),D:D)-D:D+1,1)))
```

Same as column J minus start number of each date range.

Column L works the same way as column H.